# Bulk upload million records to DB from Excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a task where user upload excel file having million records from UI and I need to validate the data and if everything is correct, it will upload all million records at single shot(bulk upload) to SQL DB.

I have been analyzing the approach how it has to be done. I get only 2 ways.

One is through UI where user uploads excel sheet and do validate check and sqlbulkcopy to Database. And the second one where user uploads the excel from UI and I will save that file in some folder and creates a SSIS package to it and run the job scheduler to run that job from the backend.

I know later one will work as we ruuning through SSIS package. But User only gets their out put when and only job runs. But My requirement needs instant output to the user whenever he uploads the application from UI. For that I should go with former. With this option I was wondering UI couldn't handle to insert million records at bulk from excel sheet.

Can some one tell me how should I move forward or What would be the best way to implement.

Comment: If you've got an application that will instantly validate and load 1 million excel records and then return them to the user (instantly) I'd love to know what you're doing. Because that sounds impossible to me. One tip that might help you is, in recent versions of SQL you can run SSIS packages using the SSISDB, as opposed to scheduling SQL agent jobs.

Comment: No one can view all million records at a time,so you can try paging approach,you can use SQLBUlKCOPY with excel as datasource and try uploading data into batches in sql server..even if your batch size is 10000 ,there is no way user can view all 10K at a time,so try inserting the data into database in a background thread using bulkcopy and when user wants to see data,start from first batch which is already inserted

you should also not use a transaction,since if this million records are inserted in one transaction,this will lock the table..

Comment: So my suggestion is have some kind of logic,which checks the rows that are inserted in case of failure and starts from there(i recommend using ASPOSE,since this allows you to treat excel rows like table
)

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thank for the answer. I am afraid I may not insert in batches. Because after user upload the excel file we are also analyzing the data and show the statistics in a dashboard. I think if we upload in batches , values on dashboard doesn't show correctly until it uploads all million records. So I have still no idea how to do that.